# I need to concatenate url with sharepoint list tr id

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I need to extract the ID from ms-unselectedtitle which is a child element of ms-vb-title in a SharePoint 2007 list. This would then be concatenated with a url to open a new window.  The window needs to open with the window.open() method so i can control the size and turn off menus. Creating a link in the list by calculated column won't work as it just opens a new window in a tab with all menus.  I found code here ("[How to get ID value from tables nested in other tables with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473803/how-to-get-id-value-from-tables-nested-in-other-tables-with-jquery)") that is close but it returns an array of ID's, not by table row.  I'm new to javascript/jquery so I'm a bit stuck.  Note that the ID I'm using is embedded in the "Title" field of the list.  Html section is here...

```
    <TD class=ms-vb-title height="100%" sizset="50" sizcache011076027996994381="6">
       <TABLE onmouseover=OnItem(this) id=284 class=ms-unselectedtitle height="100%"
    cellSpacing=0 Type="" SUrl="" UIS="1024" 
    CId="0x010010381707B6E7FC45825D794C02F54155" CType="Item" MS="0" CSrc="" HCD="" 
    COUId="" OType="0" Icon="icgen.gif||" Ext="" Perm="0x400001f07ee71bef" 
    DRef="sites/site1/M/S/Lists/MAINT_ACTIONS" Url="/sites/site1/M/S/Lists
    /MAINT_ACTIONS/284_.000" CTXName="ctx1" sizset="50" sizcache011076027996994381="6">
          <TBODY beenthere="1">
             <TR>
                <TD class=ms-vb width="100%"><A onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" 
    onfocus=OnLink(this) href="/sites/site1/M/S/Lists/MAINT_ACTIONS
    /DispForm.aspx?ID=284" target=_self>Item <IMG class=ms-hidden border=0 
    alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." src="/_layouts/images
    /blank.gif" width=1 height=1></A></TD>
                <TD><IMG style="VISIBILITY: hidden" alt=Edit src="/_layouts/images
    /menudark.gif" width=13></TD>
             </TR>
          </TBODY>
       </TABLE>
    </TD>
```

The code that is close is below...

```
    // filter out all tables with immediate parent td.ms-vb-title
    // returns a collection
    var ids = $('.ms-unselectedtitle').filter(function() {
        return $(this).parent('td').hasClass('.ms-vb-title');

    // from resulting collection, grab all IDs
    }).map(function() {
       return this.id;

    // convert to array
    }).get();
```

Could someone help me here?  Note that I'm trying to access the ID from a clickable link in the row.

Comment: Can you post some html structure? Also when you say the code you have posted is close, what does that mean. What is it returning and what should it be returning? Making an [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be optimal.

Comment: Adam, I've updated the post with a code snippet up to ms-vb-title.  Also, when I said it was close the get() method returns all IDs in the list.  However I need it to return only one ID, the one for the current row. The rows are siblings of table ms-listviewtable and have alternating names "" and "ms-alternating".

Comment: So basically on a `click` event of the `a` element inside of the `td` you want to get the ID of the `td` it belongs to?

Comment: Yes, then concat as an end filter with a url I need it to go to.  If I could get a rowIndex number that could be added to the .get() and return just the number I need.  Unless there is a simpler way.

Comment: Well yes, in this case you would just do `$(this).parent().attr('id')` in the click event.

Comment: Where would I use this?  In the return line? I tried using it there and couldn't get it to work.  Could it be that the id attribute is a sibling of ms-unselectedtitle, not a parent?

Comment: I figured out an alternate method. I was able to get the script into the SharePoint calculated column by creating two column that held part of the script then concatenating them with elements from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by creating three columns in the SharePoint list with a final one to put them together.

```
    getWin1 held ...onClick='javascript:window.open("... the first part of the
    script and was made default text for this single line text column.

    getWin2 held ...","_blank","toolbar=0,menubar=0,top=50,left=50,width=1024,
    height=800,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,location=0");return false;'... the
    second single line text column.

    getUrl concatenated the url to the ID from the list.

    =CONCATENATE("<span><input ",getWin1,getUrl,getWin2," type='image' 
    src='https://sof.socom.mil/sites/SORDAC/M/SharePoint_System_Files/Icons
    /Magnification_16.png'/></span>")... was put into the last column to
    combine the three columns.
```

I have Text to HTML CEWP to convert it to HTML script.  Not the optimal solution but it works.  Note that the ... just marks the start and end of the script.